# How Do i loop two tables in a rake task ROR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

so am writing  a system of which each user has an account and deposits.
so my user  model is:

```
    has_many :deposits
```

account model
`belongs_to :user`
deposit model
`belongs_to :user`

In my rake task
am trying to find and verify each deposit and once verified, the equivqlent is updated to the account.balance

```
  desc "Depost Verification per plans"
  task testest2: :environment do

    @users = User.all


    @users.each do |u|
      puts u.email

      u.accounts.each do |a|
      puts  a.first_name
      puts  a.balance
      end

      u.deposits.each do |d|
      puts  d.amount
      end


      @accounts = u.accounts.all
      @deposits = u.deposits.all

      @accounts.each do |b|
        puts b.first_name
      end
    print "Commands working here error begins on the next paragrah"
    print "how do i achieve this loop using the above parameters"

    @accounts.zip(@deposits).each do |account, d|
        if d.status?
        acct_bal = account.balance.to_f + d.amount.to_f
        account.update!(balance: acct_bal)
        puts account.user.username
    
        puts account.balance
        print "Deposit Added"
      else
        acct_bal = account.balance.to_f + 0.00
        account.update!(balance: acct_bal)
        puts account.user.username
        print "Deposit Unverifed"
      end
    end
    


    end


    print "command run .........."



  end
```

Bt somehow am getting this error

```
/Users/fortune/.gem/ruby/2.7.2/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
daveskeen24@gmail.com
DayTon
0.0
DayTon
Commands working here error begins on the next paragrahrails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `status?' for nil:NilClass
/Users/fortune/sites/current/dapps/dayton/lib/tasks/deposits.rake:77:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'
/Users/fortune/sites/current/dapps/dayton/lib/tasks/deposits.rake:76:in `each'
/Users/fortune/sites/current/dapps/dayton/lib/tasks/deposits.rake:76:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
```

What Do I Do.....???????????????????

Comment: How are deposits and accounts are connected to each other? Please share the associations you defined on `User`, `Account` and `Deposit`.

Comment: accounts belongs to users

Comment: deposits belongs to users

Comment: should i make deposits to belong to accounts ..?

Comment: If a deposit does not belong to an account, how do you determine which account a deposit was made into? I would expect that a user has multiple accounts and that each account has many deposits.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have less `@deposits` than `@accounts` so `d` is nil, thats the behaviour of `zip` https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip

If I think correctly what you need is to have a link in the database between deposits and accounts, then get every account and check all its related deposits.

Comment: so if deposits belongs to accounts it should work yea..?